# java:package org.openqa.selenium.html5 does not exist

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using selenium for UI testing in java.
I have a module cloned from git hub which is being used in my project.
In spite of having the latest jar dependencies in my build.gradle file(intelliJ), I'm encountering

> package org.openqa.selenium.html5 not found error

Only during **runtime**.

The selenium dependency  does not complain at compile time, but during run time I am having errors that say

> java:package org.openqa.selenium.logging does not exist
>
> java:package org.openqa.selenium.remote does not exist
>
> java:package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
>
> java:package org.openqa.selenium does not exist

I try clearing my gradle cache and re-installing the jars with the latest versions, and yet it's still the same issue.

These are the dependencies I have for selenium in my project:

```
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'
   
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'
   
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'
   
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-support', version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'
   
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-remote-driver', version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'
   
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'
```

I also tried with different versions of selenium, but nothing works.
Any solutions that I could try to fix this issue.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java can you check here for  dependencies which you want to use in your project

Comment: I already have the dependency included in my project